# How to convert scala Manifest to TypeTag?

Tags: scala, reflection, scala-2.10

TypeTag in scala 2.10 is notoriously useless as it cannot be serailized into anything else without losing higher kind information. So I'm reverting back to good old Manifest. However, some of the libraries I used still use TypeTag, to use them I have to convert Manifest into TypeTag. Is there a consistent and reliable way to do it across all scala version?

Thanks a lot for your opionion

Comment: So far as I know, there is not.